# File I/O in Python

Tags: python, csv, file-io, io

I'm attempting to read a CSV file and then write the read CSV into another CSV file.

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv 
with open ("mastertable.csv") as file:
    for row in file:
    print row  
with open("table.csv", "w") as f:
   f.write(file)
```

I eventually want to read a CSV file write to a new CSV with appended data.

I get this error when I try to run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readlines.py", line 8, in <module>
f.write(file)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

From what I understood it seems that I have to close the file, but I thought with automatically closed it?

I'm not sure why I can write a string to text but I can't simply write a CSV to another CSV almost like just making a copy by iterating over it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: [Need an answer? Actually, no... you need a question](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Comment: Now, the error seems more clear: You've already closed the `file` object, so, when you need it again in the `f.write(file)` line, it's already closed! (and again, you have an indentation problem, this time `print row` is wrong)

Comment: @Barranka: and you cannot write a file object to another file anyway. They want to copy across the *lines*, not the file object itself.

Comment: I apologize for the unspecific and open ended question.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read in a CSV and write to a different one, you might do something like this:

```
with open("table.csv", "w") as f:
    with open ("mastertable.csv") as file:
        for row in file:
           f.write(row)
```

But I would only do that if the rows needed to be edited while transcribed. For the described use case, you can simply copy it with [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) before hand then opening it to append to it. This method will be much faster, not to mention far more readable.

The `with` operator will handle file closing for you, and will close the file when you leave that block of code (given by the indentation level)

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intend to make use of the Python `csv` module. The following should be a good starting point for what you are trying to acheive:

```
import csv 

with open("mastertable.csv", "r") as file_input, open("table.csv", "wb") as file_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(file_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(file_output)

    for cols in csv_input:
        cols.append("more data")
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

This will read `mastertable.csv` file in a line at a time as a list of columns. I append an extra column, and then write each line to `table.csv`.

Note, when you leave the scope of a `with` statement, the file is automatically closed.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely the next step of what I was going to research. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The file variable is not really actual file data but it is a refernce pointer which is used to read data. When you do the following:

`with open ("mastertable.csv") as file:
        for row in file:
        print row`

file pointer get closed automatically. The write method expects a character buffer or a string as the input not a file pointer.

If you just want to copy data, you can do something like this:

```
 data = ""
 with open ("mastertable.csv","r") as file:
     data = file.read()
 with open ("table.csv","a") as file:
     file.write(data)`
```